# Appcelerator Titanium Developer with Java?

Tags: appcelerator

i just downloaded Appcelerator Titanium and experimenting with it, I selected Desktop application and to support python,PHP and Ruby but I can't find Java. how to really work with java. I just need a hint about how to get my java code working there, where to put my java files and where should I include them.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Titanium does not support java .. well not directly

But take a look at these URLs for some possible options in writing java code 
that indirectly uses titanium ..

As usual, the mileage obtained from adding a new layer of code would depend on how 
well one understands the core architecture of how all the bits plug together ..  :

- https://github.com/emitrom/titanium4j
- http://www.learningtitanium.com/software/gwt4titanium/javas-write-once-run-anywhere-for-titanium.html

As Emitron writes:

```
Titanium4j(Ti4j) is a Java application framework designed for creating rich 
and interactive native applications for mobile and desktop.

The mobile package inside Ti4j leverages Appcelerator Titanium Mobile 
to create native mobile applications.

The desktop package inside Ti4j leverages The TideSDK to create native desktop   
applications.

Titanium4j takes the underlying frameworks to another level by making you avoid 
JavaScript and puting all Java libraries and tools are at your disposal
```

You will have to decide whether the above justifies learning this extra functionality .. I reckon it does justify it